# React-Native. - Document Scan & Crop

Tags: react-native

Im currently working on a basic React-Native app that would use the camera to scan a document (passport, Driving license, utility bill) then have the option to crop the image and same to PDF.

So far i have been using **react-native-document-scanner** which works ok, but doesn't always auto select the correct portion or all of the document, in the documentation it also lists **react-native-perspective-image-cropper** which is designed to work with it to allow manual cropping of the image.

Has anyone used these 2 packages together, i am struggling to see how they work together, or is there something better i could be using.

The part that saves to PDF looks to be working ok, its more the detecting and cropping of the document that is the problem

I have looked at RNCamera but that doesn't auto detect the document border, which my client would like.

Thanks for any help